# Nhibernate HQL Subselect queries

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I have the following SQL query:

```
select c.id
from (select id from customers) c
```

This query has no practical value - I simplified it greatly for the purpose of this post.

My question: is it possible have a subquery in the from clause using HQL. If not, can I perhaps query the customers first, kinda like a temp table in sql, and then use the result as the source of the next query?

thanks

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's possible.

The query above can be written in HQL as:

```
select Id
from Customer
where Id in (select Id from Customer)
```

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work. However, when I change the subquery it works fine

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It does support subqueries, but not all of them. I'm changing my answer.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work fine - is there another solution. I dont like the IN clause - what happens if the customers table contains a 1000 entries...you will probably run into some memory issues.

Comment: That probably won't happen with your actual query (the one above doesn't make much sense). Wanna post something closer to the real one?

Answer (score 5):

I've run into this issue myself. Took me a while to realise that hql does not support subqueries in the from clause.

See section 14.13 in the hql documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html).