# Select statement in from clause in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, sql

I have three tables named:

- `schedule (id, status)`
- `criteis (id, name, number, bank)`
- `info (id, compleInfo)`

id is common for all three tables.

My req is that i want bank, number from crities table & compleInfo from info table and count of status from Schedule table.

I have used this query

```
select count(s.status), a.compleInfo, a.bank, a.number 
from (select in.compleInfo, cr.bank, cr.number 
      from criteis cr, info in  where cr.id=in.id ) a
left join schedule s on a.id = s.id group by a.id
```

It works fine on MYSQL Editor but when i run it on Hibernate i am getting below exception

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near
>   line 1, [ select count(s.status), a.compleInfo, a.bank, a.number from
>   (select in.compleInfo, cr.bank, cr.number from criteis cr, info in 
>   where cr.id=in.id )  a left join schedule s on a.id = s.id group by
>   a.id]

i googled it and found [Nhibernate HQL Subselect queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713068/nhibernate-hql-subselect-queries) that  hql does not support subqueries in the from clause.

Is there any other way to write the above query in Hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HQL allows you to walk the object tree but it's not SQL.

If you want to run SQL queries, you must use [native SQL queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html).